# How do I call a model from a module in a controller in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

This is the main.php content:

```
'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
```

where admin is a module.
In the controller  index function I have this:

```
$model = Users::model('search');
```

Where **Users** is a **model class** inside the **admin module**
I get this error message:

> include(Users.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How do i call a model from a module in my controller ?

Comment: Where is the controller located?

Comment: This issue was all my fault, There was a misspelling problem in the model name. Thx for all your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your module in controller with:

```
Yii::app()->getModule('Admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.php file register your admin module.[Link here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module#using-module)

```
   return array(
    ........,
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules' => array(     // Add your new modules here.
       "admin"=>array()
    )
    ....
 );
```